# jQueryUI draggable() does not seem to work for button element but does so for other elements

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

I have included jQuery UI in my application so page elements can be dragged. Out of necessity, I have written a function to handle draggable() (since some elements have remove() associated with them and can be re-appended later, the function needs to be called over and over) and bind dragstart and dragstop events. Basically looks like this:

```
function makeDraggable(ID) {
    $("#" + ID).draggable({
        axis: (ID === 'myElement' ? "y" : "xy"),
        scroll: false
    }).bind("dragstart", function (evt) {
       //my code
    }).bind("dragstop", function (evt) {
        //my code
    });
}
```

Div elements work fine but a submit button I cannot get to work. I changed the button from type=submit to type=button and same result. I moved the button outside its `form` parent and same result. The function makeDraggable() is called for the button in the same way as the div elements. The draggable() function is not called anywhere else on the page. The classes 'ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle' are added to the button so the function makeDraggable() is definitely firing. But dragstart doesn't fire for some reason. When I add an alert box to the dragstart:

```
function makeDraggable(ID) {
    $("#" + ID).draggable({
        axis: (ID === 'myElement' ? "y" : "xy"),
        scroll: false
    }).bind("dragstart", function (evt) {
       alert(ID);
       //my code
    }).bind("dragstop", function (evt) {
        //my code
    });
}
```

the alert box is fired for the other elements but not for the button. No console errors are thrown. I even removed the axis and scroll options but same result. Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried styling your button with `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;`?

Comment: It seems that the application globally sets a display of inline-block (not set by me). Could this be the culprit? I will try to remove this style element.

Comment: If you remove it, try adding a `display: block` rule instead. Default display style of buttons is `inline`.

Comment: Added display:block using Chrome Dev Tools but still not dragging

Comment: Try adding that style directly in the page (or in your CSS). The draggable widget may depend on it for its computations upon initialization.

Comment: I tried this and still no dragging. Not really sure what's happening here but I will probably need to come back to it later.

Comment: Yes, the cancel option worked..tyvm